# Pandas: where is my warning being triggered from?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas in my python script. After a python upgrade, my script throws up the following error:

```
/XXXX/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py:1586: FutureWarning:
Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.
```

I do not see any traceback. How do I find out which specific line in my script triggered this error? Possible answer might be applicable to other warnings as well.

Unfortunately this question was down-voted for some reason instead of helping a solution. After doing some digging, I found that the error was coming from the snippet:

```
 newDF = {} #pd.DataFrame()
 newDF["Time (ns)"] = df["Time"] / ns
 newDF["Current (kA)"] = df['Currnt'] / 1000.0
 newDF["Power-a"] = df['WSumktot'] * erg_per_sec_to_watt
 newDF["Total"] = np.array(df['WSumtot']) * erg_per_sec_to_watt
 newDF =pd.DataFrame(newDF)
 header = ["Time (ns)" , "Current (kA)", "Power_a", "Total"]

 print "before error. The following line triggers the error"
 newDF.to_csv("current_data.csv", columns=header, sep=b'\t', float_format='%.5e', index=False)
 raw_input("data saved. Press enter")
```

Comment: Please update your code snippet with the question

Comment: from reading the error it looks like you pass a list with an empty label to the `.loc` function - so you should check your input data for missing labels.

Comment: I see that. But the question is where. Any way to trap the warning and print a traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the source of the error. It is generic enough to be of use to others:

Imagine you have a dictionary:

```
  import pandas as pd
  newDF = {}
  newDF["a"] = pd.Series([1,2,3])
  newDF["b"] = pd.Series([2, 5 ,6])
  newDF["c"] = pd.Series([3, 6, 9])

  newDF =pd.DataFrame(newDF)
  header = ["a" , "b", "c"] # these names must exactly match above

  newDF.to_csv("file_data.csv", columns=header, sep=b'\t', float_format='%.5e', index=False)
```

But if one of the lines is accidentally changed:

```
 header = ["a" , "b", "c1"] # these names must exactly match above
```

The above mentioned error will be seen.